# setContentView overrides xml file

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm new on android programming, so I was trying to learn how to build my first app through the tutorial of android developer site. However, in the attempt to create a new activity, when I send the extras from my TextEdit to my TextView, android suggests that I use the method setContentView(textView) to show the message.

My guess is that the whole thing that my activity will have is this TextView. The thing is that I'm trying to change the background of this activity in the layout (xml file) by android:background...etc. but since the onCreate method runs the setContentView, I suppose that everything else is runned over (such as the TextView that has the hello world! string when i created the activity).

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Additionally: I would like to learn how to pass many extras with the same "send button", like if i have different textEdits and I would like to take their info.

And finally (sorry if it is too much), I would like to know how to put different TextViews in my new activity, so that I could like show a message in one color, and another one in a different size or color.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass extras on clicking Send button, you could use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)'s [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) method, like:

```
Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_send_button_id);
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //create Intent
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, YourNewActivity.class);
        //add extra data to intent
        sendIntent.putExtra("some_key", <SOME-VALUE-DATA>);
        CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand this part, but I would like to know if by the click of the send button I could send like a bunch of extras (like many lines of sendIntent.putExtra("some_key1", <SOME-VALUE-DATA1>); and then sendIntent.putExtra("some_key2", <SOME-VALUE-DATA2>);?

Comment: @kickingnico yes, you can either send extra individually or add all your extras i an array/object and send it all at once. Though when you want to get the sent extra, you will have to use appropriate get*() method

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will be of great help!!!